# Why NSArray does have indexOfObject method and NSMutableArray does not?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I would like to delete a specific element from a `NSMutableArray`, and I see that NSArray has `indexOfObject` method which is quite useful for this, but `NSMutableArray` does not.

My current approach is to use `removeObjectsInArray` method from `NSMutableArray` passing as an argument an array containing my object/s.

Is there a better way to do that?, is there any reason why `NSMutableArray` does not have this method?.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It does too have `-indexOfObject:`. `NSMutableArray` is a subclass of `NSArray`, and therefore inherits all its methods.

Comment: yes, you are totally right. I am quite new to objective-c and I didn't spot it. This is the link to the apple documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: A lot of people overlook the "inherits from" part of the documentation. Personally, I think it should be made a little more prominent somehow so people realize that there's a bunch of other methods that a class can respond to.